# Silverlight TextBlock - get text with ellipse

Tags: silverlight, textblock

In silverlight TextBlock, `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` is used to display ellipsis when the text is exceeding the textblock width.

Is there any way to get the display text (what is displayed in the screen) with ellipsis?

I need to place image instead of ellipsis.

Thanks
Suyambu

Answer (score -1):

To set an image as background of a Ellipse, we can set an image brush as the Fill of the Ellipse.

```
<Ellipse.Fill >
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="dock.jpg" />
</Ellipse.Fill >
```

try it and reply..